# Non $0,\pm 1$ integer coefficient polytopes with integral extreme points

Tags: discrete-mathematics, integer-programming, discrete-optimization, polytopes, network-flow

Suppose we have a linear system

$$Ax\leq b\quad \text{where}\quad A\in \mathbb{Z}^{m\times n},b\in \mathbb{Z}^m.$$

In integer programming literature,   we usually have that $A$ has only $\{0,\pm 1\}$ entries, including totally unimodular matrices.

Suppose instead $A$ is integer-valued in general, is there any well-known class of polytopes that has integer-valued extreme points in the literature?

Thanks.

Comment: "i.e. a totally unimodular matrix." ? Check the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unimodular_matrix) of a totally unimodular matrix.

Comment: Hi, I mean for example here. I changed the question slightly.

Comment: "i.e." means equivalence. It is not at all the same as "for example" (confusion between "i.e." = "id est" and "e.g."="exemplo gratia")

Comment: sorry I don't know that, thanks!